# UIImagePickerController simple way to show library button in camera

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I`m trying to show library button on camera view (UIImagePickerController). Here is my code:

```
- (void)takePhoto{
    _imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [_imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [_imagePicker setDelegate:self];
    _imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    int y = frame.size.height;
    int x = frame.size.width;

    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x-100, y-50-1, 100, 30)];
    [button setTitle:@"Library" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(gotoLibrary:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [_imagePicker.view addSubview:button];

    [self presentViewController:_imagePicker animated:NO completion:nil];


}
-(IBAction)gotoLibrary:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [imagePicker.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, 450, 350)];
    [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum];
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
    [imagePicker setDelegate:self];

    [_imagePicker presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Problem is in images when I try to take photo. How can I hide a library button when I take photo?
[image: How it looks like]

[image: And problem as this]

Comment: hi, were u able to solve this?

Comment: Joining the question 

Answer (score 0):

The poor man way to fix this problem, would be to position the label at the top, centered, so it doesn't conflict with the photo button ;)

Not the greatest fix - but its super quick